# Normal distribution approximating binomial

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

Why does the mean of the sample proportion equal the population proportion.
$E(\hat{P})=p$

The reasons that I can think of:

- As most of samples proportion you take lie on the range of the population proportion for a desired characteristic. (assuming large sample size)

But as most samples lie on the range of $p,$ why is it the average of sample proportion that equals $p$ and not the mode maybe?

I am really confused if anyone can explain this to me with examples would really help.

And why do we always talk about average/mean ?

Comment: Your question does not appear to have anything to do with approximation of a binomial distribution by a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive approach is to imagine flipping a biased coin that comes up $0\ \frac 23$ of the time and $1\ \frac 13$ of the time.  The mode of the distribution is $0$, but you would not expect that if you flipped a lot of times you would always get $0$.  You would expect to get $0\ \frac 23$ of the time and $1\ \frac 13$ of the time, so the average is $\frac 13$, the mean of the distribution.

For a real proof, look up the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).